# Can not install rfxcom binding on openhab2 on odroid

Tags: java, osgi, openhab

It looks like openhab 2 tries to load an intel binary while I have an ARM based system. Is it possible to get this running or is ODROID simply not supported. Btw. Interestingly this worked on a raspberry pi.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/odroid/openhab2/userdata/tmp/libNRJavaSerial_odroid_0/libNRJavaSerial.so: /home/odroid/openhab2/userdata/tmp/libNRJavaSerial_odroid_0/libNRJavaSerial.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
11:12:23.880 [INFO ] [me.event.ThingStatusInfoChangedEvent] -

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that openhab and especially the serial support is not fully working on 64bit java on arm. So the solution is to install the 32bit arm jre which can be found at oracle.

To make the 32bit binaries work some additional commands are needed:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:armhf
```